# Using a pointer array within a struct in Cython

Tags: python, struct, cython

I am trying to write a Cython wrapper around a C library. I am very new to Cython, so my apologies in advance if the problem is obvious.

In a file wrapper.pxd, I define a struct (reduced example):

```
cdef extern from "thiscouldbeyourlibrary.h":
    cdef struct foo:
        double **output
```

I then have a class:

```
cdef class Bar:
    cdef wrapper.foo __stuff

    cdef do_something(self):
        self.__stuff.output = NULL
```

This fails:

> Cannot convert 'void *' to Python object.

Apparently, Cython cannot be sure that self.__stuff.output is always a pointer. But I declared its type and the class is a "cdef" class, so I don't really understand why.

Comment: Note that there are better tools for the specific task of generating *Python wrappers*, like [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) (that's what `pywin32` uses).

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I know. There is actually already a wrapper for the specific library I need, based on SWIG. However, I was having some problems with it (and by "problems" I mean segfaults), and it doesn't do precisely what I want (NumPy interoperability).

Comment: Just a guess: use `None` instead of `NULL` - that looks more like a "Python object" :^)

Comment: @EyPandaBear did you check the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the incompatibility between `NULL` and `double **`. You could assign it to a `char`, `int` or `void *`, for example, doing:

wrapper.pyd:

```
cdef extern from "thiscouldbeyourlibrary.h":
    cdef struct foo:
        char a
        int b
        void *c
        double **output
```

thiscouldbeyourlibrary.h:

```
struct foo
{ 
    char a;
    int b;
    void *c;
    double **output;
};
```

main.pyx:

```
cimport wrapper

cdef class Bar:
    cdef wrapper.foo __stuff
    def __init__(self):
        self.__stuff.a = <char>NULL
        self.__stuff.b = <int>NULL
        self.__stuff.c = NULL

def main():
    bar = Bar()
    print bar.__stuff.a
    print bar.__stuff.b
```

If you had allocated the memory for `output` before, you could have done it:

```
self.__stuff.output[0] = NULL
```

without allocating it will crash...